# Не работает подключение к websocket на vds ratchet php

Tags: php, websocket, vds, ratchet

Вообще я тестировал создавая сервер на локальной машине.
Я читал документация вот [тут](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world).
Сейчас мне нужен **ratchet websocket** для своего проекта. И как обычно у меня блин все не работает.

---

### Вот что я сделал:

- Купил vds, Ubuntu 22.04.
- Скачал туда php7.2, apache, zip, composer
- Создал файл для сайта `var/www/mysite`
- ip: http://92.53.120.193/
- Скачал туда с помощи composerа `Ratchet`.
- Создал в `var/www/mysite` - `/bin/chat-server.php`, `/src/Chat.php`.
- Код идентичен документации.
- Порт 8080
- **Запустил.** Вроде работает ошибок нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Подключаюсь

Подключаюсь я с помощи javascript, с помощи моего проекта локального. Я не стал подключатся через удаленный сайт, у меня там стоит https, вы ведь понимаете я даже не могу просто осилить сервер создать. А там с https нельзя его без ssl.

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://92.53.120.193:8080');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

---

### Ошибка

Я не хотел так призентовать ошибку. Потому что она маленькая, но ужасная из-за того что я не понимаю что делать дальше. Она ни чего мне не дает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Что с этим делать? Может как то по другому apache настраивать. Или брать не vds а vps? Я много раз... Где то 5 раз точно перезаписывал код и запускал. Я Уматался я серьезно не знаю что делать. Проект уже застоялся я до сих пор не могу сдвинутся. Есть предположения? ЛЮБАЯ помощь принимается. Если есть вопросы задавайте!

Answer (score 0):

В общем то я решил проблему. Я все во лишь поменял порт 8080, на 443, 80, у меня эти 2 порта работают.

Поменял в :

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        443 // <- тут
    );

    $server->run();
?>
```

И вот тут:

```
var conn = new WebSocket("ws://92.53.120.193:443);
```

Это хоть работает, но не знаю как заставить работать с https. Вообще из-за этого больше вопросов.

Comment: для сайта на https в настройках apache наcтройте proxypass для веб-сокет сервера. Должно получиться что-то вроде `ProxyPass /wss/ ws://mysite:8080/`. Обращаться нужно будет на адрес `mysite/wss/`

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо что написали. Я сталкивался с подобным решением. Мало что понимаю.
Подскажите пожалуйста, конфигурация apache находится в `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`? Строчку `ProxyPass` нужно добавлять в самом конце файла? И в место `mysite` - писать свой ip? И почему порт 8080? Нужно ли оставлять или прописывать тот что работает у меня `80`? И обращаться нужно полностью вот так: `wss://mysite/wss/`? Извините за большие вопросы. Я даже задавал вопрос конкретно по этому вопросу ни кто не помог.

Comment: Если вам нужен протокол `wss` то вы должны брать файл конфигурации апача для `https`. `ProxyPass` нужно писать не в конце файла, посмотрите примеры. Вместо `mysite` нужно указывать либо домен (теоретически подойдёт и `localhost` т.к. всё развёрнуто на одной машине), либо `ip`. Порт `8080` потому что такой в изначальном примере, можно и другой, но не `80` или `443`. Адрес обращения выглядит правильно

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо! Буду пробовать